# Console command to respaw cell flora?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recent found out about the flora despawning bug when you reload a save.
Im in no mood for mods that just replaces problems with different problems.
Is there a command to reset the flora in a cell? Specifically, Solitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no command to reset the state of plants. I've researched this like 2 years ago(because I've met this bug as well), sadly there was no commands that respawns plants(and/or ores.)

Fortunately(at least for me, since you aren't going to use mod I think?), I've found a [mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/13186) that fixes this problem. However:

> Q: Will this mod fix stuff I've already harvested?
>
> A: People keep asking this question in the comment thread, and I thought I
> had explained how this work pretty well, but apparently not. I'll try
> again:
>
> The rule is: stuff you've never harvested before, is automatically
> fixed. There is no need to worry about it at all. It just works.
> However, **stuff you've harvested before is not fixed until you install**
> **this mod and harvest it again**.
>
> So for example, if there are 50 plants in an area, but you only ever
> harvested one of them, then the 49 of them will be fixed as soon as
> you install the plugin and you don't have to worry about them at all.
> It is only that one, which you will have to harvest once before it is
> fixed. That's why, when you visit an area after installing this mod,
> if there are any flora you want to fix, you should harvest them right
> away if they have respawned.

Quote from that mod's description, emphasis mine.

I hope it helps.